# db connection in form validation - WEB.PY - PYTHON

Tags: python, database, forms, validation, web.py

my first question here, perhaps a noob question but I really don't understand what I'm doing wrong, and I can't find any clue on the web.py documentation.

Is it possible to use a db select to validate a field?

What I'm doing:
I'm building a registration form, I'm having trouble with the username validation.
In every example I found, users are declared in a variable before the registration Class with code like this:

```
allowed = (
    ('jon','pass1'),
    ('tom','pass2')
)
```

and used in the validation like this:

```
form.Validator('Username already exists.', lambda x: x not in allowed)
```

Since I'm saving in db, I can change the allowed tuples with a db.select, but this mean the select is performed only once.
I want to check the users every time the POST is called, so I just replaced the "allowed" variable with a db.select this way:

```
 form.Validator('Username already exists.', lambda x: x not in [o.usr for o in db.select('users',what='usr')])
```

If I test "x not in [o.usr..etc..etc..]" on the interpreter, this work..

```
>>> [o.usr for o in db.select('users',what='usr')]
0.0 (1): SELECT usr FROM users
[u'hhh', u'Fede', u'Vinz', u'Patro', u'Codino', u'Codino']
>>> x = "Fede"
>>> x not in [o.usr for o in db.select('users',what='usr')]
0.0 (2): SELECT usr FROM users
False
```

But when I run the code and I make a new registration with an existing username nothing happens.. as you can see the "Codino" username is been registered twice.

What I'm doing wrong?

..and more interesting: there is a smarter way to block the registration of an already used username?

Thanks,
Federico

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you already have an answer with this one since it's an old thread. 
Here's what I did on checking if username already exist.

I create a validator such as these:

```
vuser_exist = form.Validator("Username already exist.", lambda u: u is None or model.get_user(u.username) is None)

register_form = form.Form(
form.Textbox("username", vuser_req, vuser_length, description="Username"),    
form.Button("submit", type="submit", description="Register"),
validators = [vuser_exist],
)
```

In model.py

```
def get_user(user):
try:
    return db.select('users', where='user=$user', vars=locals())[0]
except IndexError:
    return None
```